# Unwanted body margin when browser is horizontally shortened

Tags: html, css

Whenever I make my browser smaller horizontally, I get a fixed header that behaves as it is supposed to but the body content is then capable of scrolling horizontally. Why is this? For example, here is an image of what happens when the browser window is scaled to its minimum width.

[image]

I have the following to my body

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 170%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    max-height: 46px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to answer you unless you share your code.

Comment: Are you already using the [viewport meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) tag?

Comment: `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">` yeah

Comment: Can we see the HTML, too?

Comment: html is, everything is in the body but footer and header both have divs

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem. There must be something else going on in code we can't see. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the styles of your header and the elements inside your header. I don't know what you currently have, but you can try to add these styles to both your header and body:

```
position: relative;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
```